# While Loop Error: ParseInt

Tags: java, while-loop, parseint

I do not get any errors in my code, but when I run my code and enter in an input for `number` that's greater than 1, I don't get more `JOptionPane` window to input records of data into like I'm trying to. Could anyone please inform me on how to solve this issue please?

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;   
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.io.FileWriter;  

    public class CreateData {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
          "this program writes payroll data",
          "Welcome", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        int repeat = 1;
        String answer;

        do
        {
            Write();

            answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("write payroll data?\n" + "enter 1 to continue or 0 to exit");
            repeat = Integer.parseInt(answer);

        } while(repeat==1);

        System.exit(1);
    }

    static void Write()
    {
      try { 
        String firstLine, secondLine, thirdLine, number;
        number = null;
        firstLine = secondLine = thirdLine = "";
        File check = new File("payroll.txt");  
        FileWriter file;
        if(check.exists()) 
          file = new FileWriter("payroll.txt", true);
        else
          file = new FileWriter("payroll.txt"); 

        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(file);
        int size = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while(number == null || number.equals("")) 
        {
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("how many records?");
        }

        size = Integer.parseInt(number, 10);

         do { 

          while(firstLine == null || firstLine.equals("")) 
          {
          firstLine = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name");
          }

          while(secondLine == null || secondLine.equals("")) 
          {  
          secondLine = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hours");
          }

          while(thirdLine == null || thirdLine.equals("")) 
          {     
          thirdLine = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter wage");
          }

          buffer.write(firstLine);
          buffer.newLine();
          buffer.write(secondLine);
          buffer.newLine();
          buffer.write(thirdLine);
          buffer.newLine();
          count++;

        }while(count < size);

        buffer.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data processed",
        "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );



        }//end of try

      catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }  


    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you enter that for `number` and not for `answer` that will break the "input loop" if you enter something else than *1*?

Answer (score 0):

This program seems familiar...

The reason you don't get any more dialogs is that after the first round, all your variables contain values that are neither null nor empty. So the while conditions are not met. If you want the dialog to display, the best would be to set the variable to null just before the while loop.

E.g.:

```
secondLine = null;
while(secondLine == null || secondLine.equals("")) {
     secondLine = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hours");
}
```